# Custom strcpy function not returning expected pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *str_cpy(char *, char *);
void main()
{
    char *desti= (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),10);
    char *m= (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),10);
    m = str_cpy(desti,"dhawal");
    printf("destination string is :%s\n",desti);
    printf("%s\n",m);

}

char *str_cpy(char *a,char *b)
{
    while(*b!='\0')
    {
        *a = *b;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
    *a = '\0';
    return a;
}
```

Please explain why `m` is not assigned with value of `desti` here?

It assigns a value to a third variable the result of string copy

Comment: Can you provide example output?

Comment: For one, thats called a *memory leak*. The allocation assigned to `m`'s initialization is gone to the cosmos on the very next line. Secondly, `m` gets the **last** value that `a` held in your function, and it *wasn't* the address it had going in.

Comment: The return type of `main()` needs to be `int`. And why would `m` be assigned the value of `desti` when you're assigning it the address of the terminating null character you appended to the end of `desti`?

Comment: And you've quite possibly won the prize for *worst title of the day*

Comment: @Praetorian - As it is C the return type can be `void`

Comment: @Praetorian: It's a pretty stiff competition.

Comment: @EdHeal I'll admit I'm not as familiar with C as I am with C++, but I thought the two agreed in this regard. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/241631) says so too.

Comment: @Praetorian - For historical reasons it can have a return type `void` even though it is not good practice.

Answer (score 6):

1. You have a memory leak.
2. `desti` will contain "dhawal"
3. `m` will point to the  null character of that string. That is the same value as `a` at the end of `str_cpy`

To avoid this use

```
char *str_cpy(char *a,char *b)
{
    char *r=a;
    while(*b!='\0')
    {
        *a = *b;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
    *a = '\0';
    return r;
}
```

Comment: One more for your list - the return type of `main`

Comment: how will m point to the null character of that string. I am new to C so please bear with me?

Comment: char *copyString(char *,char *);
    void main()
    {

    char *second= (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),10) ;
    char *third= (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),10) ;
    third = copyString("aashay",second);
    printf("%s \n", second);
    printf("%s \n",third);
    }
    char *copyString(char *a,char *b)
    {
    int i=0;
    while(*(a+i)!='\0')
    {
    *(b+i)=*(a+i);
    i++;
    }
    *(b+i)='\0';
    return b;
    }

Comment: @user3690211 - In your code you return `a` that points to the null character. Also `m` will no longer pointer to the address returned by `calloc`. You will need to add `free` to the end of `main`

Comment: @ Ed Heal- thanks but please explain how the second code snippet works without memory leak?

Comment: @user3690211 - The second code snippet still has a memory leak. You need to add free. But in you code you have lost to the pointer to be used in the free call